# android frame by frame animation - differences with these two codes

Tags: android, animation, frame, runnable

I would like to animate some images.
Could someone tell me why this first piece of code does not work, but the second one does work ?
And if I have to use the second one, how do I STOP the animation into the runnable ?

EDIT : the first code works on android 4.x, but not on 2.2 (both simulator and device)

**code 1 (into "onCreate()" ):**

```
ImageView boule = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.boule);  
boule.setImageBitmap(null);
boule.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.anime);
AnimationDrawable animation = (AnimationDrawable)boule.getBackground();
animation.start();
// does not animate anything...
```

**code 2 (also into "onCreate()" ) :**

```
ImageView boule = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.boule);
boule.setImageBitmap(null);
boule.setBackgroundResource( R.anim.anime );
final AnimationDrawable animation = (AnimationDrawable) boule.getBackground();
boule.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if ( animation != null ) animation.start();
        }
    });
// OK, it works, but how do I stop this ?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.. this code works properly

```
BitmapDrawable frame1 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.jth);
BitmapDrawable frame2 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.jthj);
int duration = 10;
final AnimationDrawable ad = new AnimationDrawable();
ad.setOneShot(false);
ad.addFrame(frame1, duration);
ad.addFrame(frame2, duration);
iv.setBackgroundDrawable(ad);
ad.setVisible(true, true);
```

Put ad.start(); in button onClickListener  and ad.stop(); for stop animantion

Comment: Thanks, Shail, but it doesn't work. I've put all your code in the onCreate method (after replacing resource with my own), then add "ad.start()" below, and... nothing happens. I just see the first image.